# Read strings from a standard input, and find the most duplicated word

Tags: c++, beginner, strings

- Write a program to read strings from standard input looking for duplicated words.
- The program should find places in the input where one word is followed immediately by itself.
- Keep track of the largest number of times a single repetition occurs and which word is repeated.
- Print the maximum number of duplicates, or else print a message saying that no word was repeated.

---

For example, if the input is

- how now now now brown cow cow

the output should indicate that the word now occurred three times.

---

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    using std::cin; using std::cout; using std::endl;
    using std::string;

    // running median
    string most_duplicated_str;
    int most_duplicated_count = 0;

    // loop variables
    string prev_str;
    string new_str;
    int new_duplicate_count = 1;

    while(cin >> new_str)
    {
        if (new_str != prev_str)
        {
            // check and update median
            if (new_duplicate_count > most_duplicated_count)
            {
                most_duplicated_str = prev_str;
                most_duplicated_count = new_duplicate_count;
            }

            // update prev_str
            new_duplicate_count = 1;
            prev_str = new_str;
            continue;
        }

        ++new_duplicate_count;
        prev_str = new_str;
    }

    // check and update median for last word
    if (new_duplicate_count > most_duplicated_count)
    {
        most_duplicated_str = prev_str;
        most_duplicated_count = new_duplicate_count;
    }

    // print result
    if(most_duplicated_count == 0)
        cout << "# No Duplicated Words #\n";
    else
        cout << "Most duplicated word: " << most_duplicated_str << ", " << most_duplicated_count << " times.\n";
}
```

Comment: Sure you need to keep track of all words and their counts until there are only "M" words left (where M < the distinct words) at that point you can throw away the counts for the words that couldn't possibly be in the total.   Of course it's just easier to count them all, and then pick the max;

Comment: It's not clear to me from those misty 'rules' if in `blue blue red red red blue green blue` the `blue` should be output as the word with most occurences (4) or the `red` as the word with most occurences _in a row_ (3).

Comment: There is [median](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median), and there is [mode](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mode_(statistics)).

Comment: @MrR I ALWAYS forget about short circuit stuff like this. Thanks for the tip - I'll change it to do that tonight!

Comment: @CiaPan Yeah it's kinda wack how the book asks me questions sometimes, but I just took it as the in a row thing

Comment: @greybeard wow I really need to go back and look at my maths knowledge... Messed that up hahaha

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing awful here.

If this was production code then putting things in named functions would be nice to help with self documenting code.

---

Don't particularly like this.

```
    using std::cin; using std::cout; using std::endl;
    using std::string;
```

But I am not going to complain about it very much.

---

Using snake case is unusual but not unheard of in C++.

```
    string most_duplicated_str;
    int most_duplicated_count = 0;
```

Like the long descriptive names and the grouping of you variables into logical combinations.

---

I would note that:

```
      cin >> new_str
```

Reads a white space separated word. For college and learning purposes this will be fine. But in real life you would have to consider punctuation and other non alphabetical content and what to do with it.

---

Not a very useful comment.
I would either make it more descriptive (more words) or remove it.

```
    // loop variables
```

and

```
            // update prev_str
```

---

These three lines can be simplified:

```
            new_duplicate_count = 1;
            prev_str = new_str;
            continue;
```

to:

```
            new_duplicate_count = 0;
```

It will have the same effect and the loop will feel more logical as the same action happens every loop. But that's just my opinion on readability. If you did not change it I would not oppose it being merged into mainline.

---

If any words are read: Can the value ever be zero?

```
    // print result
    if(most_duplicated_count == 0)
        cout << "# No Duplicated Words #\n";
    else
```

If you only have a duplicate count of `1` were there any duplicates?
What happens if there are ties in the number of duplicate counts?

These are good questions to ask your customer! :-)

Comment: Thank you so much for the awesome & detailed answer!

I did want to use functions, but the book I'm going through hasn't introduced them yet, so I didn't want to skip ahead too much.

I see a lot of debate around namespace techniques. Do you prefer fully qualifiying everything?

Regarding cin, is there a good resource for standard input reading techniques for stuff like this?

I totally missed that simplification! Is there any way I can get around doing that final check of repeated code after the while?

Comment: `Do you prefer fully qualifiying everything?` Depends on context. If I am using code from another namespace I will fully qualify it.  `std::cin << "Info\n";` If the namespace is too long I will add a namespace alias and use that: `namespace  BSL = boost::Butcher::Streaming::Logs;  BSL::log << "Info\n";` If this is code for my code and I am in the source file for a specific header file that uses a namespace I will use `using namespace ThorsAnvil::DB::Access;` [See](https://github.com/Loki-Astari/ThorsDB/blob/master/src/ThorsDB/Statement.cpp)

Comment: `Regarding cin, is there a good resource for standard input reading techniques for stuff like this?` Sorry this is just tuff you learn as you go. I don't have any good references except SO and this site. Don't miss the use of `operator>>` and `std::getline()` use one or the other. Lots of SO questions on that subject.

Comment: Snake case isn't so unusual in C++: there's an entire Standard Library leading the way...

Comment: @TobySpeight Which one? Don't particularly have any objects to snake case (just the use of prefix _) but it is not my favorite (the _ is in a funny place on the keyboard for a lot of repetitive use). As long as people are consistent I am happy (consistent means we can automate things).

Comment: @TobySpeight If its only one standard library. Then could we not say that's its unusual as only one out of n (a lot) use it? :-)  Yea OK its the standard library so it is being normalized that way.

Comment: Personally, snake-case is fine (for me, `_` is on the home row, and it's often useful to be able to easily select or step over "sub-words" in identifiers, which gets hard using case-transition as word boundary).  That said, I agree that remaining consistent is more important (even if that internal consistency is inconsistent with the Standard Library - and if you use any library with a different convention, then you can't agree with them all unless you somehow manage to use single words everywhere!).

Comment: @TobySpeight No argument `snake_case` is fine (even if we disagree on if it is unusual or not). :-)

Answer (score 1):

## Create a testable function

Instead of plonking everything in `main()`, I would prefer to see a function which can be tested with many different inputs from one program (perhaps accepting a `std::istream&`, or maybe a pair of iterators to words).

Yes, you could write a shell script to invoke the program with different input streams, but that gets awkward when we want to test different parts of a larger program.  Let's develop the habit of coding for testability right from the start.

One advantage of writing the tests as we go is that it helps us understand how the function will be called, leading us to a better interface.  And we can investigate the edge cases (what if there are two words with the same repeat count?  How should we deal with two different runs of the same word?).

## Know your standard `<algorithm>`s

If we read input using a `std::istream_iterator<std::string>`, then we could use `std::adjacent_difference()` to compare consecutive words and maintain count, without having to hand-roll our own loops.  Or we might (ab)use `std::adjacent_find()` or `std::unique()`, both of which have Ranges versions.